# in discord.py, How do I make a bot command that reaches multiple replies, saving the data into a variable?

Tags: bots, discord.py

I want to be able to create a command that lets me get a response from a user which will then be saved as a variable, that'll be saved into another file for safekeeping.
(an example would be making a character sheet in direct messages, where you need to input multiple messages to get the desired outcome.)
I'm stuck and need help with finding a reliable way to make replies and to be able to stock the ones sent by the user. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure, but i think what you are looking for is **wait_for**

There are two examples in the discord.py docs, the first example covers wait_for message. It can be found on this url: https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=wait_for#discord.Client.wait_for